# C++ libcurl PATCH request not working with stringstream conversion via .str.c_str()

Tags: c++, json, curl, format, libcurl

I am sending a patch request via C++ libcurl library, it works 100% without any issues when I hardcode the "payload" into my program, however, I want it to be passed in so I used stringstream to create it. When I am sending it with stringstream the server responds with 400 Bad request whereas when I manually input it, the program runs with no errors

This is how it looks (and works) when I hardcode it in

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"region\":\"us-central\"}");`

This is how I formatted it with stringstream (which for some reason does not work

```
stringstream payload;
payload << "{\"region\":\"";
payload << c_codes[i];
payload << "\"}";
```

and in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` I called it as payload.str().c_str()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`payload.str()` returns a temporary. Then `c_str()` gets a pointer to the sequence of characters managed by that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed, and the characters with it; the pointer becomes dangling. Then cURL sends whatever garbage happens to be in the memory pointed to by that pointer, memory that once held character data but doesn't anymore.

You need something like

```
std::string data = payload.str();
curl_easy_setopt(..., data.c_str());
```

and then make sure that `data` is alive all the time while the request is processed.

Comment: or you could have used [CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, then payload.str().c_str() would have been safe, and you don't have to care about the lifetime of the strings, curl would keep (a copy of the) string alive for you.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is as [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55987822/1067003) described, but i just want to post an alternative solution:

you can use [CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, then payload.str().c_str() would have been safe because curl would have made a copy of the string for you, and the lifetime of the string is no longer your responsibility, it's curl's.